# Django: Save id on a OneToOneField

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

models:

```
class UserDataUpdate(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserSurvey(models.Model):
    about_treatment = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    user_data_update = OneToOneField(UserDataUpdate)
```

views:

```
@login_required
def generate_survey(request):
    user_data_update = UserDataUpdate.objects.get(code=request.user.username)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/success')
    else:
        form = SurveyForm(request.GET)
    return render_to_response(
        'survey.html',
        {'form': form },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

form:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget = RadioSelect(choices=SURVEY_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        exclude = ['user_data_update']
```

I just need a way to set the UserDataUpdate id (that already has been created) on a UserSurvey.

I'm getting this message on generate_survey request.POST:

```
user_data_update_app_usersurvey.user_data_update_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear to you that you get the `user_data_update` value but then don't do anything with it. I guess you want to set it on the object that's created by the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user_data_update = user_data_update
    instance.save()
```

(I don't understand what all that stuff in the form's `__init__` method is supposed to do. You only have one field in your form, anyway.)

Comment: It's lacking lots of attributes on this UserSurvey, comparing to the original one. The idea on this form was to set all fields to use RadioSelect rendering with a single CHOICE. By the way, thanks for the example, it's working pretty well. Never used (commit=False) to create an mutable object. Awesome!